# Should an end tag close all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags?

Tags: html, html4, sgml

Am I reading the HTML 4.01 standard wrong, or is Google? In HTML 4.01, if I write:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html> <head> <body>plain <em>+em <strong>+strong </em>-em
```

The rendering in Google Chrome is:

> plain +*em* +***strong*** -**em**

This seems to contradict the HTML 4.01 standard, which summarizes the underlying SGML rules as: “an end tag closes, back to the matching start tag, all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags”.[¹](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1)

That is, the `</em>` end tag should close not only the `<em>` start tag but also the unclosed intervening `<strong>` start tag, and the rendering should be:

> plain +*em* +***strong*** -em

A commenter pointed out that it is bad practice to leave tags open, but this is only an academic example. An equally good example would be: `<em> +em <strong> +strong </em> -em </strong>`. It was my understanding from the HTML 4.01 standard that this code fragment would not work as intended because of the overlapping elements: the `</em>` end tag should implicitly close the `<strong>`. The fact that it did work as intended was surprising, and this is what led to my question.

And it turned out I proposed a false dichotomy in the question: neither Google nor I were reading the HTML 4.01 standard wrong. A private correspondent at *w3.org* pointed me to *Web SGML and HTML 4.0 Explained* by Martin Bryan, which explains that “[t]he parsing program will automatically close any currently open embedded element **which has been declared as having omissible end-tags** when it encounters an end-tag for a higher level element. (**If an embedded element whose end-tag cannot be omitted is still open, however, the program will report an error in the coding**.)”[²](http://www.is-thought.co.uk/book/sgml-9.htm#Omitting) (Emphasis added.) Bryan’s summarization of the SGML standard is right, and HTML 4.01’s summarization is wrong.

Comment: If browsers adhered to the standards strictly, then most of the WWW would be unreadable by humans... so they don't. Browsers parse and render pages for the common cases, even if they are incorrect/not-valid according to the standard.

Comment: That's a really bad practice you're doing there. Never you should rely on browsers to take care of your code. General rule of HTML is to close all open tags and to keep hierarchy. You code should be something like: <html> <head> </head> <body>plain <em>+em <strong>+strong </strong></em><strong>-em</strong> </body></html> Or even better, use CSS to define those styles rather than using `em` and `strong` tags.

Comment: IE, Firefox and Chrome presents the same results.

Comment: As per the above comment, this appears to be a global thing among all browsers. Every browser I checked will close the `<strong>` element and then reopen it after closing the `<em>` element, then close all the elements for the end of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement quoted from the HTML 4.01 specification is very obscure, or just plain wrong on all accounts. HTML 4.01 has specific rules for end tag omission, and these rules depend on the element. For example, the end tag of a `p` element may be omitted, the end tag of an `em` may never be omitted. The statement in the specification probably *tries* to say that an end tag implicitly closes any inner elements that have not yet been closed, *to the extent that end tag omission is allowed*.

No browser has ever implement HTML 4.01 (or any earlier HTML specification) as defined, with the SGML features that are formally part of it. Anything that the HTML specifications say about SGML should be taken as just theoretical until proven otherwise.

HTML5 doesn’t change the rules of the game in this respect, except that it writes down the [error handling rules](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-end.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser). In simple issues like these, the rules just make the traditional browser behavior a norm. They are tagsoup-oriented, treating *certain* tags more or less as formatting commands: `<em>` means “italicize,” `</em>` means “stop italicizing,” etc. But HTML5 also takes measures to define error handling more formally so that despite such tag soup usage, it is well-defined what document tree in the DOM will be constructed.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to the idea that "to the extent that end tag omission is allowed" is implied by the statement in the specification, but is there any justification for believing it? For example is there anyplace a person could go to see whatever written discussion there was about the wording of it?

Comment: A construct like `<em>+em <strong>+strong </em>` is incorrect by the formal rules of HTML, as defined in the DTDs. So if a prose statement in a spec seems to say that it is correct and has a specific meaning, we must be misinterpreting the statement (or the spec is really self-contradictory). But perhaps most convincingly, the statement being discussed starts with “Please consult the SGML standard for information about rules governing elements”, and the continuation is just a parenthetic note. So it cannot possibly be meant to violate SGML rules.

Comment: This answer is best because it not only answers the question in the title but identifies the root cause of my confusion: poor wording of the spec. The spec should have used the wording in the Martin Bryan document that I linked in my comment on the question. I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Some tags are allowed to be omitted (such as the end tag for `<p>` or the start and end tags for `<body>`), and some are not (such as the end tag for `<strong>`). It is the former that the section of the spec you quote is referring to. You can identify them by the [use of a dash in the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3):

```
<!ELEMENT P - O (%inline;)*            -- paragraph -->
  ^A p element
            ^ requires a start tag
              ^ has optional end tag
                 ^ contains zero or more inline things
                                       ^ Comment: Is a paragraph
```

What you have is not an HTML document with an omitted tag, but and invalid pseudo-HTML document that browsers will try to perform error recovery on.

The specification (for HTML 4) does not describe how to perform error recovery, that is left up to browsers.

Comment: *Error recovery* is a nice choice. It is a formally defined term, and it is also something easy to understand by those not into language theory/parsing. The term describes precisely what the browsers are doing.

Comment: "Error recovery" is a complete myth. Browsers do nothing of the sort. They follow [the Mosaic paradigm](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html/1999Dec/0044.html) and implement a point-command conception of the syntax borrowed from SGML (See Jukka's answer above).

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it could do better to address the question's main point about why `<strong>` isn't implicitly closed by the closure of its containing `<em>` span, as shown in the example. The accepted answer does that better.

Answer (score 1):

The specification says that:

`Some HTML element types allow authors to omit end tags (e.g., the P and LI element types).`

This:

`Please consult the SGML standard for information about rules governing elements (e.g., they must be properly nested, an end tag closes, back to the matching start tag, all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags (section 7.5.1), etc.).`

Applies to elements which can have omitted end tags.

If you look the [P](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-P) element spec you will see:

Start tag: **required**, End tag: **optional**

So, when you use this:

```
<DIV>
<P>This is the paragraph.
</DIV>
```

The `P` element will be automatically closed.

But, if you look at the [EM](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-EM) spec, you will see:

Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

So this rule of automatic closing is not valid since the HTML is not valid.

Curiously all the browsers presented the same behavior with that kind of invalid HTML.

Comment: It's not that curious that all browsers do the same thing here. This pattern is a *very* common authoring mistake, and many authors have relied on the behaviour of the most popular browser of the day (Netscape at one time, IE later), so each browser has, to be compatible with the extant web, had to do the same thing. The HTML5 spec formalises the algorithm, but it just describes what browsers have done ever since they first started building an internal object model.

Comment: What is your source or rationale for believing that where the standard says "all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags" it actually means "all unclosed intervening start tags with omitted end tags, **but only for those elements for which end tags are mandatory**"? Because that is not what the standard says.

Comment: The browsers will behave according to spec in a well formatted HTML. For invalid HTML the rules don't apply.

Answer (score 0):

All modern browsers use an HTML5 parser (even for *HTML 4.01* content), so the parsing rules of HTML5 apply. You can find more information at the [*Parsing HTML Documents* section in the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#parsing).

**HTML Outline**

- **HTML**

  - **HEAD**

    - *#text* " " ()
  - **BODY**

    - *#text* "plain " ()
    - **EM**

      - *#text* "+em " (italic)
      - **STRONG**

        - *#text* "+strong " (bold/italic)
    - **STRONG**

      - *#text* "-em" (bold)

Comment: Ok, you couldn't find the specific line that might contradict the HTML 4.01 standard? Instead you linked us to a mile long page that *may* contain something specifically related to the subject.

Comment: I'm looking into it. In the meantime, at least pointing everyone in the right direction (since the HTML 4.01 standard does not apply for modern browsers) is more helpful than not giving anything.

Comment: If you feed the browser a document which declares itself to be HTML 4.01 strict, and the browser applies HTML 5 parsing rules, the browser is doing it wrong. So wrong that I find this claim very hard to believe.

Comment: When you use the DOCTYPE, the browser must behave like as the DOCTYPE says. Indeed the HTML5 is backward compatible, so this rule applies to HTML5.

Comment: @rogelware, that's how DOCTYPES were intended to be used, but in practice, they are not. Perfect example: Browsers do not fail upon coming across invalid code in XHTML documents unless the server sends the correct header (which typically has to be set up manually by the server operator).

Comment: @MetaEd, HTML5 has been written in a way that it is mostly backward-compatible with previously written specifications for HTML. The problem was the parsing process was never fully documents, so browsers had to guess and backward engineer other implementations. In the end, each browser parsed HTML documents differently so it was one of the goals of the HTML5 spec to properly document what should occur when parsing. Also, HTML5 does not require any extra information in the DOCTYPE except `<!DOCTYPE html>` because, in fact, browsers never really paid attention to all of that extra information.

Comment: I agree, but the HTML5 spec is not changing the rules here.

Comment: @rogelware, is that from research or guessing? I'll be looking through the spec later tonight and doing the parsing by hand to see what should actually happen according to the spec, but if you already have, I won't worry about it.

Comment: Research.. I have posted a solution... read down there... there are references to the spec explaining what is happening.

Comment: @animuson - The relevant part of the HTML5 spec parser rules is the algorithm to [reconstruct the active formatting elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#reconstruct-the-active-formatting-elements), but Jukka provides a link to somewhat friendlier text on the matter.

Answer (score -2):

If you try running your HTML through http://validator.w3.org/check it will flag up this HTML as being pretty much invalid.

If your HTML is invalid, all bets are off, and different browsers may render your HTML differently.

Answer (score -2):

If you look at the D.O.M. in Chrome by right clicking and saying inspect element, you'll be able to deduce that since your tags do not match up, it applied an algorithm to decide where you messed up.  Technically, it does close the strong tag at the correct place. However, It decides that you were probably trying to make both pieces of text bold, so it puts the last -em in an entirely new, extra "strong" element while keeping the '+strong' in it's own "strong" element.  It looks to me like the chrome team decided it is statistically likely that you want both things to be bold.